# How can I include an external markdown file in my Jekyll page?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I have a Jekyll site. I have a part of the homepage where content goes. Initially, I created a `.md` file in `_includes/`. I added `{% include myContent.md %}`. This worked.

Then I realized that the Markdown file was nearly identical to my repository's `README.md` file. Ideally, I could edit one and they would both change.

I can access my `README.md`. (E.g.: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/react/master/README.md)

Is there an elegant way in which I can include this as part of my site? I tried `{% include https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/react/master/README.md %}`. It did not work.

(Sidenote: Where can I get the URL for my repository's social media image? I'd rather not have it uploaded to my site and to GitHub if it can be more elegant.)

Comment: I was trying to do the exact same thing for the exact same reason. I settled to instead leaving most of the documentation in the `README.md` and having the readme link to additional pages.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible. According to the [Jekyll documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/), `include` only lets you include

> the content from another file stored in the _includes folder

Another option, `include_relative`, will let you

> include file fragments relative to the current file

You are limited to including relative files in the current directory or lower, higher-level directories aren't able to be included in this manner.

I imagine it's not allowed as a security measure - although I'm not able to come up with a feasible attack vector if they were to allow it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin called [jekyll-remote-include](https://github.com/netrics/jekyll-remote-include) for this.

Once installed:

```
{% remote_include https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jekyll/jekyll/master/README.markdown %}
```